Does darkvision work underwater? How?
The rules for underwater combat visibility on page 117 of the DMG seem vague and do not make any mention of the benefits of darkvision.  Nor do they specifically mention that the 60 foot encounter distance (which we assume is the furthest any creature can see underwater, regardless of darkvision) in clear water with bright light is due to obscurement.  What it does say, in part, is

Unless the characters have light sources, use the Underwater Encounter Distance table to determine the distance at which characters underwater become aware of a possible encounter.

This leads us to believe that:
IF
there was a light source, (e.g., the continual flame spell cast on an object)
AND
the water condition was clear and dark
THEN
all creatures, regardless of darkvision, would be able to see out to 40 feet, albeit with perception penalties.
Here's where the question comes in:
If that continual flame were to be extinguished, what prevents a creature with 60 feet of darkvision from seeing out to 60 feet?

You have quoted all relevant rules, except for the one on page 5 of the Dungeon Master's Guide:

Part 3 : Master of Rules
(...)
The rules don’t account for every possible situation that might arise during a typical D&D session.

Rules are not meant to cover each and all situations, just the most common. When DM sees something not covered by the rules, he is meant to make a ruling.

If that continual flame were to be extinguished, what prevents a creature with 60 feet of darkvision from seeing out to 60 feet?

The direct answer is - whatever DM rules to. Water might not be that clear. Or water may be clear and DM is allowed to rule that character with darkvision indeed sees out to 60 feet and start encounters at this distance. Or in your world darkvision is heat based and cold water messes it up? Rules simply aren't that specific. But the DM should be.

The rules for Darkvision state:

Darkvision
A monster with darkvision can see in the dark within a specific radius. The monster can see in dim light within the radius as if it were bright light, and in darkness as if it were dim light. The monster can't discern color in darkness, only shades of gray. Many creatures that live underground have this special sense.

The rules, that you link to, for underwater visibility (DMG, page 117) state:

Underwater Visibility
Visibility underwater depends on water clarity and the available light. Unless the characters have light sources, use the Underwater Encounter Distance table to determine the distance at which characters underwater become aware of a possible encounter.
Underwater Encounter Distance



Creature Size
Encounter Distance




Clear water, bright light
60 ft.


Clear water, dim light
30 ft.


Murky water or no light
10 ft.




So for Darkvision, the light category gets treated as if it were one better and the  table would be:
Underwater Encounter Distance with Darkvision



Creature Size
Encounter Distance




Clear water, bright or dim light
60 ft.


Clear water, no light
30 ft.


Murky water
10 ft.




Given how many deep sea and Elemental Plane of Water dwelling creatures have Darkvision, it would be pretty weird if it never provided any benefit (Leviathans are "usually found only on the Elemental Plane of Water, so it would be weird to have 60' Darkvision that only kicks in on the rare occasions they manage to reach the Material and surface), so this is clearly rules as intended as well.

"So for Darkvision, the light category gets treated as if it were one better..." I like this ruling, but you might want to point out that it is in fact a ruling and not from the rules themselves.

@JoakimM.H. The rules have 3 light categories - bright, dim and no light. The darkvision rules states to treat dim as bright and no light as dim. The rules can be paraphrased as  stating that, when using darkvision, the light category gets treated as if it were one level better. I don't know what you mean by saying that it is a ruling that is not in the rules because the long-hand version is in the rules (as per my first quote).

@MT0 Yeah, I agree!
